# SoftLayer API doesn't recognize new Datacenter (osl01)

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

As shown below, the new SoftLayer Datacenter in Norway is not recognized by the API.  This call works with other Datacenters.

```
SoftLayer.managers.hardware._get_location(package, "osl01")

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerError: Could not find valid location for: 'osl01'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to replicate this using Bare Metal (Package 200) as a test. Can you specify which package ID you are seeing this with?

```
import SoftLayer
import json

package_id = 200
datacenter = 'osl01'

client = SoftLayer.Client()

location_object_filter = {
    'name': {'operation': datacenter}
}

location_object_mask = "priceGroups"

location = client["SoftLayer_Location_Datacenter"].getDatacenters(filter=location_object_filter, mask=location_object_mask)

if len(location) == 0:
    # error handling
    exit()

# lookup location group ids
location_group_ids = []
for location_group in location[0]["priceGroups"]:
    location_group_ids.append(location_group["id"])

object_filter_standard = {
    'items': {
        "prices": {
            "locationGroupId": {
                "operation": "is null"
            }
        }
    }
}

standard_items = client["SoftLayer_Product_Package"].getItems(id=package_id, filter=object_filter_standard)

object_filter_location = {
    'items': {
        "prices": {
            "locationGroupId": {
                "operation": "in",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "name": "data",
                        "value": location_group_ids
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}

location_items = client["SoftLayer_Product_Package"].getItems(id=package_id, filter=object_filter_location)

# let's key by item id
items = {}

for standard_item in standard_items:
    for location_item in location_items:
        if location_item["id"] == standard_item["id"]:
            items[location_item["id"]] = location_item
            break

    if standard_item["id"] not in items:
        items[standard_item["id"]] = standard_item


print(json.dumps(items, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

Comment: That is odd, I am not able to replicate this with 257 or 251. If you are able to use the code example here  https://softlayer.github.io/python/location_based_pricing/ then it may be with the Python manager (helper). If that is the case you may want to open an issue at https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/issues.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide information about how are you getting **package** object? or the object that you are sending?

> The package **257** has "Oslo 1" datacenter in regions assigned, but
>   for **251** package is expected, because the package has not available
>   "Oslo 1" as a region

Comment: Does this help?

`File "/home/blueboxadmin/sambol/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/managers/hardware.py", line 738, in _get_location
    % location)
SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerError: Could not find valid location for: 'osl01'`

Comment: Well, it's necessary to get the way that you are getting the **package**, because if you print **package['regions']**, I'm really sure that you don't have 'Oslo 1' as datacenter, this method **_get_location** just gets the specific region from the **package** object that you send, so the issue is in the way that you are getting **package** object

Comment: Here's how we're getting the package: https://gist.github.com/msambol/20ab5b573a45494a207e26a959d55a61

Comment: I'm able to get the package but you're correct in that **package['regions']** does _not_ have **osl01** in it. Is this a fault in our code or yours?

Comment: That's your fault, because as I told you before:

**The package 257 has "Oslo 1" datacenter in regions assigned, but for 251 package is expected, because the package has not available "Oslo 1" as a region**

So, it would be really important to get the way that you are getting package variable, in order to verify why you are not able to see **Oslo 1**